# HTML escaping in a form

Tags: html, escaping

I want to send a value including "> like this:

```
<input name="address" value=""><SCRIPT SRC='http://site.com/js.js'></SCRIPT>">
```

I want to send the exact value `"><SCRIPT SRC='http://site.com/js.js'></SCRIPT>` So how can I escape this and use it in a html form? OR is there any other methods?

Comment: `<input />` is a self closing tag. Your markup is invalid. You'll need to put the `<script></script>` tag inside the `value=""` attribute of the `<input />` tag. There's several functions that escape values for you. You may want to look into ***escape***, ***encodeURI***, and ***encodeURIComponent***.

Comment: I want to send my value starting with ">

Comment: You're markup remains invalid. **Anything** you want to send must be in the `value` attribute between the quotations (""). Also depending on your `!DOCTYPE` you may need to have the `input` tag as a self closing tag `<input />`. I know you do for xhtml but I think html5 will let it slide. Not sure what you are using, but keep that in mind...

Comment: yes yes I know it is invalid. I want to some how send some kind of a value using "> part in front eg:- ">hey. Any idea you can share?

Answer (score 1):

First, change your HTML to this :

```
<input name="address" value="><SCRIPT SRC='http://site.com/js.js'></SCRIPT>" />
```

If you want to put some quotes, use the escape string `\"` like this :

```
<input name="address" value="\"><SCRIPT SRC='http://site.com/js.js'></SCRIPT>" />
```

Comment: Hello, I want to send the exact value "><SCRIPT SRC='http://site.com/js.js'></SCRIPT>

Comment: With the semicolon at the end? I've updated my answer for your needs... But my answers are just to point you the way. Of course you can change it!

Comment: sorry about the semicolon stackoverflow automatically adds it. btw in your solution ><SCRIPT SRC='http://site.com/js.js'></SCRIPT> 
is only displayed as the value. How can we add "><SCRIPT SRC='http://site.com/js.js'></SCRIPT>